# How can I save an .xlsx file as Unicode text using interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have to build a report making desktop application . I need it to be really user friendly, the reports are in Hebrew so it has to be Unicode and not just a regular .csv file or I get question marks.. I want to receive the file path of the report (like `c:\folder\file.xlsx`) and be able to save a copy of the original file in another location as a Unicode text file.. Help?

Same problem as [this guy](http://forums.asp.net/t/1770270.aspx).

"I need to use the saveas() from Microsoft.office.interop.excel but I can't figure how to do it "

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Which library are you using? What is the error message? What is an *address*?

Comment: Thanks! I know all of my required functions are in Microsoft.office.interop.excel but I'm struggling to figure how to use it.. I'm a complete novice, just a month into c#.. And by address I meant filepath

Comment: Is this a desktop application? What do you mean by "save a copy as text file"? Please add your question to add these (and more) details.

Comment: Try [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). You'll get first results soon.

Comment: @HansKesting is it clearer now?

Comment: Excel files are binary, you can't read them or store them as text. The question makes no sense as is. Are you sure you have a real Excel file instead eg of a csv file with a fake extension?

Comment: @Thomas I'm a military developer, I have no access to the Internet (outside my phone)

Comment: How are you reading the Excel file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I save them as Unicode text and then read them, but I want my application to do that for the users instead of them doing the "hard work"

Comment: @user4903602 Are you sure your files are xlsx files and not csv files?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin 100% sure, without a shadow of a doubt

Comment: @user4903602 it's impossible to help if you don't post the code you are using to *read* the file. There are multiple ways to do that, some of which treat text as ASCII instead of Unicode. If you are asking in general how to do this - use EPPlus or Microsoft's Open XML SDK, eg: [How to Open a spreadsheet document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc823095.aspx).

Comment: @user4903602 also note that `xlsx` files are zipped XML files with UTF8 encoding. If you have encoding problems, it's in how you read the file or how you save the output file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can read it just fine, that's not the issue I'm having.. I need to use the saveas() from Microsoft.office.interop.excel but I can't figure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then use this code:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();

try
{
    app.DisplayAlerts = false;
    app.Visible = false;

    Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\test.xlsx");

    book.SaveAs(Filename: "D:\\test.txt", FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText,
        AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        ConflictResolution: Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
}
finally
{
    app.Quit();
}
```

`"D:\\test.xlsx"` is your input excel filename and `"D:\\test.txt"` is your unicode text output filename.